# What is the function $\psi$ inside level set definitions for shape functionals?

Tags: optimization

In the level set method for shape optimization the shape functionals are defined as:

$$J_{dom}(\Omega) = \int_{\Omega} \psi (x) dx, J_{bd}(\Omega) = \int_{\partial \Omega} \psi(x) d \mathcal{H}^{d-1}$$

and $\Omega$ is related via a level set function $\phi$.

What is the function $\psi$ inside level set definitions for shape functionals? Where is it gotten from?

Comment: I will be direct:  I have had a look at your profile: you ask too many questions: for example, you have sent the present question only some minutes after another one. It's not like this that you will suceed. Moreover, **you never (or almost never) validate one of the given answers**. Some of them must be good, don't you think ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for reminding.